# How do you make a lowercase field in a django model?

Tags: django, django-models

With this method, I can make a field save as lowercase, but this does not
change the field in the existing model (that is in memory).

```
def get_prep_value(self, value):
    value = super(LowercaseField, self).get_prep_value(value)
    if value is not None:
        value = value.lower()
    return value
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to force this field to lowercase without overriding save and doing the change there.  But that splits the logic for this lowercase field.  I'd like all of it in the field.  What do I override so that setting this value forces lowercase in memory AND on in the DB?

I don't want to change a form, I want all the lowercase logic contained inside the field class.

---

I've found a partial work around like so:

```
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    """ Returns field's value just before saving. """
    attr =  getattr(model_instance, self.attname)
    if attr is not None:
        attr = attr.lower()
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, attr)
    return attr

def get_prep_value(self, value):
    value = super(LowercaseField, self).get_prep_value(value)
    if value is not None:
        value = value.lower()
    return value
```

It has a bit of a code smell, and does not handle checking the value before a save, but I don't see how to do that without overriding setattr on the actual model class and catching dealing with that inside the model class itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can override the "save" method in Django by adding the following code in your models.py file

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.yourfiled = self.yourfield.lower()
    return super(ModelsName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Of course is possible to handle all params with a loop.

For all existing record you can create a Management command that can convert all strings to lowercase
here the docs:
[Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales)

If you don't want to change the Save method, just add to the form the "|lower" tag that will be convert all string to lowercase in UI

```
{{ value|lower }}
```