# Convert into lower case while saving in database Django

Tags: python, django

I am adding few names in my database using the admin panel. How can I convert the the name string to lowercase before saving?

My models.py currently looks this :

```
from os import name
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Certificate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", primary_key=True)
    CertID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.today().year)

def __str__(self):
    return self.CertID
```

My admin.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Certificate


class AdminCertificate(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['CertID','name','event','year']


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Certificate, AdminCertificate)
```

Comment: you need to post your codes as well.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330677/django-model-set-default-charfield-in-lowercase) answer your question?

Comment: yeah, i did....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a lowercase field in a django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574940/how-do-you-make-a-lowercase-field-in-a-django-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this by overriding the [`get_prep_value()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-python-objects-to-query-values) method.

```
class NameField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NameField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).lower()

class Certificate(models.Model):
    name = NameField(max_length=50, default="", primary_key=True)
    CertID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.today().year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but most SQL databases support *collations* which are case insensitive.  For example, on MySQL you could create such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    c1 VARCHAR(10)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci;
```

Were you insert any text from the above character set, its case would not matter.  This means you wouldn't have to do any special handling from your Django code, you could just store regardless of case.

Comment: This will affect the whole table, not only a single field as requested.

Comment: @stalker92 Good point, but columns can also have their own collations.  This answer might be useful to someone so I'll leave it here.